# How to make a part of context to other colors in Word Cloud using R language?

Tags: r, csv, word-cloud, wordcloud2

I have a CSV file need to use Wordcloud to show the result, but I got some problem cannot to solve.

Although I can set a single color, I cannot make specific text to other colors.

For example, I want to make "369" to other colors.

The following is my WordCloud Picture.

[image: Fig1]

However, I can set only single color......

The following is my code, I can set only a single color......

```
library(wordcloud2)

input_file <- 'BLUE_Sorter_for_Emoji.csv'
df <- read.csv(input_file, encoding = 'utf-8')
#data(df)
wordcloud2(df, size=2, color = 'black', minRotation = -pi/2, maxRotation = -pi/2, rotateRatio = 0)
```

I hope I can set the following result. It can set some contexts to other colors.

[image: Example]

Moreover, the following is my CSV file：

[image: csv file]

Can anyone help me? Thanks~~

Comment: As is mentioned in the documentation, `color` argument of `wordcloud2()` function can take a vector of colors. Ex) `wordcloud2(demoFreq, color = ifelse(demoFreq[, 2] > 20, 'red', 'skyblue'))` (I got this code from the documentation.)

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use frequency to show the result. I want to use the tag to show the result......

Comment: What is more, I want to use the tag to make different colors, such as negative sentiment set red color, and then positive sentiment set blue color.

Comment: It is just an example, you can change the vector as you like, such as `color = c("red", rep("black", 200))`. For the example you gave above (change color of 369), `color = ifelse(df$Emoji=="369", "red", "black")`. Or if you want to change colors based on word sentiments, suppose you have a vector of word sentiments as `vec_word_senti`, then `color = ifelse(vec_word_senti>0, "blue", "red")`.